# Dojo 1.4 - IE 8 dojox.charting label not shown -> dojox.gfx

Tags: internet-explorer-8, dojo, charts, label, dojox.gfx

I have a problem concerning dojox.charting, after updating to the new version of dojo IE 8 doesn't show the labels of my charts anymore. Seems to be a dojox.gfx text problem.

See with IE8:
http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.4.0/dojo-release-1.4.0/dojox/gfx/tests/test_text.html

Any idea how to fix that?

Cheers

-jstr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some IE8 fix pushed by MS broke it because we didn't modify this code for a long time.

In any case there is a ticket for this problem (reported as a charting ticket): http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10491

One simple fix for now is to force IE7 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=7” />
```

More info can be found in [Understanding Compatibility Modes in Internet Explorer 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx).